# how to pass to cli util gdbus emit signal with types uint8 int16?

Tags: command-line, dbus

How to pass to cli util gdbus emit signal with types uint8 int16?

For example

```
sudo gdbus emit --system --object-path /com/application --signal com.application.example "[{'ThisisString', [{'FirstString', 'NextString', [{1, 2, 3}]}]}]"
```

On that result I've got 1,2,3 as int32

How to specify rule for values???
Thank's in advance

Answer (score 0):

I've found solution to use structures instead of dictionary on DBUS. Solution looks like:

```
sudo gdbus emit --system --object-path /com/example/obj --signal com.example.obj "[('ThisIsString', [('FirstString','SecondString',[(byte 1,byte 5,byte 10),(byte 2,byte 3,byte 8),(byte 3,byte 9,byte 15)])])]"
```